# What is the matter with wine 1.6 in PPA:ubuntu-wine/ppa?

Tags: 12.04, wine

I use `ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa` in 12.04. 
Today when I update system , it remove my old wine 1.5, but 1.6 can not be installed.

What about you ? Thanks

Edit: I use 'apt-get dist-upgrade' to update system.

Now I first remove wine 1.5 and install wine 1.6 .

```
$ sudo apt-get install wine
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  ttf-umefont libipc-run-perl libnet-ip-perl diffstat libnet-dns-perl
  libclone-perl libsbsms10 libportsmf0 language-pack-kde-zh-hans-base
  libio-pty-perl wine-gecko1.4 wine-gecko1.4:i386 wine-gecko1.9
  wine-gecko1.9:i386 audacity-data language-pack-kde-en kde-l10n-engb
  libnet-domain-tld-perl language-pack-kde-zh-hant-base libemail-valid-perl
  ttf-unfonts-core libvamp-hostsdk3 kde-l10n-zhcn language-pack-kde-zh-hans
  language-pack-kde-zh-hant kde-l10n-zhtw language-pack-kde-en-base
  libdigest-hmac-perl
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  wine1.6 wine1.6-amd64 wine1.6-i386:i386
Suggested packages:
  dosbox:any
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  wine wine1.6 wine1.6-amd64 wine1.6-i386:i386
0 upgraded, 4 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/50.2 MB of archives.
After this operation, 246 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? 
Selecting previously unselected package wine1.6-amd64.
(Reading database ... 397044 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking wine1.6-amd64 (from .../wine1.6-amd64_1.6~rc2-0ubuntu1~ppa1_amd64.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package wine1.6-i386:i386.
Unpacking wine1.6-i386:i386 (from .../wine1.6-i386_1.6~rc2-0ubuntu1~ppa1_i386.deb) ...
Unpacking wine1.6 (from .../wine1.6_1.6~rc2-0ubuntu1~ppa1_amd64.deb) ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/wine1.6_1.6~rc2-0ubuntu1~ppa1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/wine64-preloader', which is also in package wine1.6-amd64 1.6~rc2-0ubuntu1~ppa1
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Selecting previously unselected package wine.
Unpacking wine (from .../wine_1.6~rc2-0ubuntu1~ppa1_amd64.deb) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/wine1.6_1.6~rc2-0ubuntu1~ppa1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: How are doing this?  The steps?

Comment: Please use paste.ubuntu.com and add the whole output of `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[stemberk's post in ubuntuforums.org](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2154621&page=2&p=12693297#post12693297) has a solution for those who attempted the installation:

```
sudo apt-get -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-overwrite" -f install
```

This command will force the failed installation of wine to resume, with ignoring any conflicts.
[According to launchpad.net](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/wine/+bug/1191276) the bugfix is underway. Hopefully they fix it soon...

**EDIT:** It appears that the fixed package is released, but if you already installed wine1.6 using any workarounds, I'll recommend you to uninstall wine at least once (`sudo apt-get remove wine1.6`) then install it nomally (`sudo apt-get install wine1.6`), otherwise any further attempts to upgrade wine will fail.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue : /usr/bin/wine64 and /usr/bin/wine64-preloader are in both wine1.6 and wine1.6-amd64 packages.

As a (hopefully) temporary workaround I've issued the following commands:

```
sudo dpkg-divert --package wine1.6-amd64 --add /usr/bin/wine64
sudo dpkg-divert --package wine1.6-amd64 --add /usr/bin/wine64-preloader
```

This instructs dpkg to move aside every version of those files, except the one from the wine1.6-amd64 package.